# VUE NPM import package to all other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

having vue 3 npm app. I need to use jquery. So I npm installed jquery packaged.
Now if I need to use it I just do:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

This works but I have to do it in every single file! Isnt there a way to import jquery just in the most parent script (ie main.js or App.vue) and not to importi it in every single file like that? I use jquery in every file.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in `main.js` to allow access it from anywhere using `this.$`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import jQuery from "jquery";

Vue.prototype.$= jQuery;

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added this code into my main.js

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Not sure that it is the best solution for me everything is working fine.